# When the subject of a sentence is the same as the object of the previous sentence

Tags: word-choice, literary-techniques

What is it called when the subject of a sentence is the same as the object of the previous sentence?

For example:

> *I'm going to Freddy's house. Freddy lives down the block. The block is paved with gravel. The gravel is jagged.*

Comment: Given these two pairs of sentences, I'd say the proper word is _verbose_: "I'm going **down the block** to Freddy's house." and "The block is paved with **jagged** gravel." Otherwise, it's called _baby talk_, because only a book for very young children would be written this way.

Comment: There's no English word for it. The Greeks probably had a term, but then they had a term for everything, and nobody uses them any more.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You could call it *anaphora*, which basically means "repetition", but that's less specific. I doubt whether there is a word for this that is actually in use; why do you need a special word? One could argue that this style is characterised by excessively short and numerous sentences.

Comment: [Anadiplosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplosis) is used in this passage, but that has no bearing on which words are subject and object.

Comment: @tylerharms:  Not being terribly computer savvy, I can't help but ask you how you provide the OP with a hyperlink by simply typing one word, instead of by copying and pasting a complete address?  If the procedure is too involved, perhaps you could send me to a website that 'splains it real good?!

Comment: Anadiplosis is what I was looking for. I've always thought it sounded very stupid and I wanted to put a name to it. Now I can say "Stop using anadiplosis! You sound like you just got off the boat!"

Comment: @user44653: If you click on the help link under the Add Comment button to the right of the comment box, it will explain how it's done. Basically though, put the word/phrase you want linked in brackets and then, without spacing, put the link address next to it in parentheses. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a specific term that denotes the use of the object of the previous sentence as the subject of the next. But your sentences follow a common pattern in English syntax called Given-New. Speakers and writers typically start with information that is known to the recipient and follow it with new information.

There is a good introduction to this here: *[Given-New](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Given-Before-New-Principle.htm)*.